# How does persistence work in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ 5.x when using kahadb for persistence all the files are managed in a single database. This can have serious consequences.

I have hundreds of queues that see millions of messages per day. If a consumer of a queue is temporarily stopped for maintenance reasons the queues continue to fill and empty, and the one whose consumer is suspended sees the messages accumulate. But on the disc it is different. Kahadb indeed marks the deleted (consumed) messages, but cannot free the place if a more present message is kept in the database. This is the case with those that accumulate in the suspended queue.
Very quickly the disk space is full.
To remedy this, you have to change the configuration and use mkahadb. In this case there is one database per queue and therefore on the disk only the suspended queue takes up space.

I am considering switching to Artemis. But the persistence has been completely redesigned. So what happens in terms of disk occupancy when suspending a consumer?

Comment: Any feedback here? Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty broad, but I'll take a crack at it...

By default ActiveMQ Artemis uses a file-based journal. The journal consists of a pool of files that can grow and shrink based on configuration (see `journal-min-files` and `journal-pool-files` in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/persistence.html)). The size of each file is also configurable (i.e. via `journal-file-size`).

An initial pool of files will be created when the broker starts and as messages are stored and the initial pool of files fills up then additional files will be created. As messages are consumed the pool can shrink through a process called "compaction" which is also configurable (see `journal-compact-min-files` and `journal-compact-percentage` in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/persistence.html)). As long as 1 record in a journal file is considered "live" (e.g. an unconsumed message) then the whole journal file will remain. However, you can tune the impact of this to fit your environment (e.g. by lowering the `journal-file-size`, making compaction more aggressive, etc.). To be clear, if compaction runs and there is a journal file with only 1 "live" record that means all the other journal files are "full" and at most you will only ever have 1 journal file like that.

Also, you can configure [`max-disk-usage`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#max-disk-usage) to block producers from sending more messages once disk utilization reaches a certain point.

Ultimately, if a consumer becomes inactive (for whatever reason) then the messages that consumer was supposed to receive will accumulate in the queues (and potentially on disk). If you want to prevent messages from accumulating in the first place you could implement [flow control](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html) or [blocking](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#blocking-producers) for producers. However, even if they do accumulate the file-based journal should be able to grow and shrink as needed.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly there is no way to guarantee that only the payload is kept. (as with mkahadb)
But we can limit the size of the pages and fix their number.

Considering the very large number of queues I have to manage, I think the best is to divide this into a cluster. But I am worried. because when an application is in maintenace (and I have 10 000) the messages of the others cannot be erased because the messages accumulate in a queue. It is clear that whatever the configuration in a few seconds I will crash or stop.

I am surprised to see stop communication between two applications because two others no longer communicate with each other. This is a strong limitation compared to ActiveMQ.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score -1):

this will limit the problem but not solve it.
with mkahadb if I have 2 queues A and B, that A receives a message every second and B receives 5000/s and the consumers of B consume them immediately. the queue B is always empty or almost and occupies very little disk. If the consumer of A is stopped. the queue A increases but the queue B does not occupy more disk.

With Artemis if I reduce the journal size to 5000. Every second a journal file is full and deleted. If A stops, there must be 1 message from A in the journal. We therefore keep 5000 messages on the disk every second. Although queue B is almost always empty. if I reduce the journal size to 500 I keep less messages but it still grows 500 times faster than with mkahaDB. And if I reduce the journal to 1 to get the same result as with mkahadb, but I force Artemis to handle millions of files which collapses the perf.

I have the impression that Artémis is not made to have very large numbers of queues contrary to ActiveMQ.
thank

Comment: *What* will limit the problem but not solve it? This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question but rather a comment, although it's not clear what the comment pertains to. Please clarify.